# Alternatives to month-by-month Nitrous.IO billing

Tags: nitrousio

Are there any alternatives (or plans to create them) for quarterly or annual billing for Nitrous.IO? It works great for our company, but is supported on a "file an expense report each month for your bill" - which isn't great for the developers(we don't like them having to worry about expense reports every month). A quarterly, yearly, or larger period to buy service for would be more convenient.